# Data cannot be coerced into data frame

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to webscrape data but am unable to coerce the data into a data.frame for analysis. I am currently trying to scrape data from a review site, and scraped comments (which returned [10]) and ratings (which returned [80])

Here is my code:

```
library("rvest")
reviews <- read_html("https://thesmartlocal.com/reviews/singapore/eateries/cafes-eateries/fusion-cafes-restaurants/saizeriya/reviews/")

#Comments scraped
    comments <- html_nodes(reviews, ".jrReviewComment div")
    html_text(comments)

#Ratings scraped
    ratings <- html_nodes(reviews, "#jr-pagenav-ajax .jrRatingValue , #jr-pagenav-ajax .jrRatingLabel")
    html_text(ratings)

    library(readr)
    reviews_df <- data.frame(
    Comments =comments,
    Ratings =ratings
    )
```

I tried

```
reviews_df <- data.frame(
    Comments =comments,
    Ratings =ratings
    )
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
> cannot coerce class ‘"xml_nodeset"’ to a data.frame

I also tried

`Comment= data.frame(comment)`

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
> cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

`Ratings = data.frame(ratings)`

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
> cannot coerce class ‘"xml_nodeset"’ to a data.frame

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513555/6946122: `ratings = bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(ratings), function(x) data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))`

Comment: I will recommend to use xpath `res = html_nodes(reviews, xpath = "//div[@class='jrReviewListDetail']//div[@itemprop='review']")
html_text(res[1])`

Comment: Can't see any comments on the webpage you have mentioned.