# XML_Nodeset to Dataframe

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrape data from the futbin website and place this into a dataframe. I've used SelectorGadget tool to provide me with the xpath for the categories and numbers I am after from the url link below

```
url <- "https://www.futbin.com/21/player/30101"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "sub_stat", " "))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "stat_val", " " ))]')
```

This gives me this....which is a good start

```
{xml_nodeset (58)}
 [1] <div id="sub-acceleration-val-0" class="stat_val stat_text_dark_green  acceleration-val-0" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n               ...
 [2] <div class="stat_val">93</div>
 [3] <div id="sub-sprintspeed-val-0" class="stat_val stat_text_green  sprintspeed-val-0" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                      ...
 [4] <div class="stat_val">88</div>
 [5] <div id="sub-positioning-val-0" class="stat_val stat_text_dark_green  positioning-val-0" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                 ...
 [6] <div class="stat_val">90</div>
 [7] <div id="sub-finishing-val-0" class="stat_val stat_text_green  finishing-val-0" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                          ...
 [8] <div class="stat_val">84</div>
 [9] <div id="sub-shotpower-val-0" class="stat_val stat_text_dark_green  shotpower-val-0" style="display: inline-block;">\r\n                     ...
[10] <div class="stat_val">94</div>
```

I've then tried this: [Convert xml_nodeset to data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511885/convert-xml-nodeset-to-data-frame) but it doesn't keep the values (output below), presumably as the value required is on the following row in the above nodeset.

```
                           id                                                  class                  style
1       sub-acceleration-val-0      stat_val stat_text_dark_green  acceleration-val-0 display: inline-block;
2                         <NA>                                               stat_val                   <NA>
3        sub-sprintspeed-val-0            stat_val stat_text_green  sprintspeed-val-0 display: inline-block;
4                         <NA>                                               stat_val                   <NA>
5        sub-positioning-val-0       stat_val stat_text_dark_green  positioning-val-0 display: inline-block;
6                         <NA>                                               stat_val                   <NA>
```

I'd like to get the xml_nodeset into a dataframe with the even rows moved up a row alongside the previous odd row, for example,

```
         Column A.            Column B
1        Nodeset Row 1        Nodeset Row 2
2        Nodeset Row 3        Nodeset Row 4
3        Nodeset Row 5        Nodeset Row 6
4        Nodeset Row 7        Nodeset Row 8
5        Nodeset Row 9        Nodeset Row 10
```

I can then trim that into this for the final piece

```
     Attribute.            Value
1    Acceleration           93
2    Sprint Speed           88
3    Positioning            90
4    Finishing              84
5    Shot Power             94
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a diofferent approach, using the json-data provided on the site

```
library(xml2)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)

url %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all("//div[@id='player_stats_json' and position()=2]") %>%
  xml2::xml_text() %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% t()
  
#                   [,1]
# test                 0
# ppace               90
# pshooting           88
# ppassing            92
# pdribbling          95
# pdefending          91
# pphysical           88
# acceleration        93
# sprintspeed         88
# agility             86
# balance             98
# reactions           93
# ballcontrol         97
# dribbling           95
# positioning         90
# finishing           84
# shotpower           94
# longshotsaccuracy   92
# volleys             76
# penalties           84
# interceptions       93
# headingaccuracy     70
# marking             92
# standingtackle      96
# slidingtackle       85
# vision              96
# crossing            82
# freekickaccuracy    67
# shortpassing        99
# longpassing         94
# curve               85
# jumping             84
# stamina             94
# strength            84
# aggression          93
# composure           98
```

Comment: 1) Nice work! I really like that, much more simple. One follow up, could you just upskill me in what this bit is or what it's doing so I know for future reference.....

"//div[@id='player_stats_json' and position()=2]"

2) Strangely "Defensive Awareness" isn't pulled through

Comment: That is the xpath to select the right div-node

Comment: Never mind about point 2. It's pulling in under 'Marking'. Older variation but I know now so can work around it anyhow